# "ADD TO CART" button not working in product view page in magento

Tags: magento

we want customers to enter zip code on product view page to find delivery is available or not for that zip code.

so we used this extension : product-delivery-check-by-zip-code magento extension

we got what we needed by this extension. but after using this extension, "add to cart" button on product

view page is not working, also product images are not zooming as before.

seems this is the file for displaying on product view page

app\design\frontend\default\default\template\techinflo\checkavailability\availability.phtml

availability.phtml code here : http://pastebin.com/YpuwTkFS

demo : http://demo1.kidsdial.com/index.php/electronics/24-widescreen-flat-panel-lcd-monitor.html

please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is imho not related to the avaiability. The Button "add to Cart" calls a JS method to submit the respective Form. However, you have some JS issues on that page that prevent any JS excecution - maybe due to jQuery incompatibility or other. Take a look at your browsers console to see all errors

```css
TypeError: jQuery(...).dcSocialShare is not a function intel-core-2-extreme-qx9775-3-20ghz-retail.html:727:0
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2:0
TypeError: jQuery(...).viewPC is not a function em0113.js:372:5
TypeError: jQuery(...).csslider is not a function intel-core-2-extreme-qx9775-3-20ghz-retail.html:486:0
TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js:69:81
TypeError: jQuery(...).ajaxForm is not a function em_ajaxcart.js:275:8
```

and resolve them. That should also restore all other JS dependent functions like the image zoom.

Comment: Well, that is a problem that is not related to the original question. As to why you have JS issues, you would have to debug your whole setup. That is not really feasible just by looking at the page. Important thing is: Your add to cart method does not work due to other JS issues. It is NOT related to just the .phtml file.

Comment: thanks a lot , after installing extension only i am facing these problems. so from that availability.phtml file only reason to display in product view page. so that js scripts present in that FILE MAY BE PROBLEM FOR "add to cart" button.... but still i can not able to find solution.....

Answer (score 0):

in my case it got solved by unticking "Merge JavaScript Files" (system > configuration > developer)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
From http://localhost/magento2community/
to http://127.0.0.1/magento2community/
```